# What does the line in bold mean regarding $monitor in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

This is from Verilog IEEE reference manual:

> "The $monitor and $strobe system tasks (see 17.1) create monitor events for their arguments. These events are continuously re-enabled in every successive time step. **The monitor events are unique in that they cannot create any other events.**"

What does the line in bold mean?

Link for the manual: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/fa06/Labs/verilog-ieee.pdf

Topic 5.3, Page 78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Verilog 1364-2001 LRM is 18 years old and has been updated several times.

The current LRM has completely re-written this section and formally defined this as the *postponed* event region. This is the last event region before advancing time to the next time slot. All other regions have the opportunity to schedule more events and repeat event regions. The Postponed region is read-only.

For both `$monitor` and `$strobe`, this means that the signals it prints are the final values for that time slot. There is no possibility for further changes to the signals in the current time slot.